# How can I inititalise jScrollPane only when an element has an overflow scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, browser-scrollbars

I have some `ul` elements with `overflow: auto`. Most of them don't overflow but a few of them do. I want to initialise jScrollPane only on those elements that have overflow, that have a scrollbar.

I can't see an obvious way in the docs to do this!

Perhaps I need to detect the presence of a scrollbar in some other way and then nest my jScrollPane initialisation inside that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the contents of the ul element is bigger than the display size of the ul with the following code:

```
$(yourobject).attr('scrollHeight') > $(yourobject).height()
```

You can use the jQuery filter operation to filter your query.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs. Just what I need.